# Kuberntes egress traffic NAT ip

Tags: kubernetes

I want to connect to service in network outside the k8s cluster. Where this service  auth request by IP address. State when each worker nat request with their ip is inconvenient. How to achieve one ip for egress or ip per group of pods run in k8s?
My k8s cluster is install on-premise and has flannel.

I looked on Istio or kube-static-egress-ip. There are more alternatives?

Comment: You can also accomplish it with terraform, by using NAT Gateway Terraform Module https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-nat-gateway#nat-gateway-terraform-module

Comment: Also, if you are using GCP you can set static IP for cloud NAT gateway  https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview